# RegEx for parsing addresses in a required format

Tags: regex

I'm working on parsing Address fields using regex. How do I include certain patterns?

**Case 1:**

```
Address Format : (House_NMBR)(SPACE)(STREET)
```

For parsing House_Number in AddressLine field which starts with number. -/ symbols are allowed. Single letters are also allowed in the house nmbr.

Below are some of the acceptable data for House Number:

**Expected Data:**

> 11
>
> 11-11
>
> 11-11-11
>
> 11 A
>
> 11A
>
> 11/A
>
> 11/ A,

I have written the regex below,

**Regex Pattern**

```
(^[0-9]+[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[-]?[\/]?[0-9]?[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[-]?[\/]?[0-9]?[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[,]?)
```

It parses 1-1-1 or 11-11, but does not parse 111-111.

**Case 2:**

```
Address Format : (HouseNmbrExtension)(space)(HouseNumber)
```

There are list of words possibly could come such as Floor Numbers(1st FL,2nd FL) or  Suite, Level etc followed by number. The numberpattern after last space goes to housenumber part.

**Expected Data:**

> LEVEL 12 333 >> Level 12 (HouseNmbrExtension), 333 (HouseNumber)
>
> SUITE32 33/44 >> SUITE32 (HouseNmbrExtension), 33/44 (HouseNumber)
>
> 1st FLOOR 300 >> 1st FLOOR (HouseNmbrExtension), 300 (HouseNumber)
>
> 3rd FL 900 >> 3rd FL (HouseNmbrExtension), 900 (HouseNumber)
>
> Unit 12 22A >> Unit 12 (HouseNmbrExtension), 22A (HouseNumber)

**Regex Pattern:**

```
(Level ?.*|Suite [0-9]+?[-]?[0-9]??.*|Unit [0-9]+?[-]?[0-9]?|Tower ?.*|.* Floor?.*|FL ?.*|.*?)
\s
(^[0-9]+[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[-]?[\/]?[0-9]?[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[-]?[\/]?[0-9]?[\s]?[A-Za-z]{0,1}[,]?)
```

But, result is not coming as expected.

How do I get the patterns correctly parsed?

Comment: IMO you would need to have different regexes for various cases and test one by one which matches whole input and then use this to extract information and fields from the input. One regex for all these cases would be an impossible monster IMO

Comment: For case1 for matching House_NMBR data, you can use this [`^\d+(?:[- \/]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*,?`](https://regex101.com/r/4O0vGR/1/) and for case2, why don't you simple use this [`(.+) +(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/JEv2jB/1/) regex, because in case2 you are literally allowing anything so what's the point of even hardcoding strings that have you seen so far? Your case2 regex will keep getting updated as you see new kind of data in your real examples.

Comment: Although if you really wanna try for case2, a more neat regex that matches your current samples can be written as this [`^((?:LEVEL|SUITE|Unit) *\d+|\d+[a-z]{2} +FL(?:OOR)?) +(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/JEv2jB/2/)

Comment: Why not `(.*) ([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$` ? House number seems well defined, and you are not really normalizing the other part anyways.

Comment: You need to describe in words what your rules are.  You've just given examples, but that's not enough to know what the regex should be.

Comment: I suppose rules needs to be derived looking at the data, mainly because, these addresses doesn't seem to be generated through some kind of rules, instead looks like are hand entered by normal people, and indeed what makes this problem a little non trivial to solve.